# Performance problems with NC523SFP 2x10G NIC

Tags: networking

First of all hello to all forum members. This is my first post here.

I am facing a problem with my servers after installing a new 2x10G NIC (HP NC523SFP). I have 8 Fujitsu RX1330 M3 (Intel E3-1230 v3), 2 HP DL320e (Intel E3-1230 v3) and 3 Supermicro (Intel E5-1650v4) servers.
Tried installing the NC523SFP 10G NIC in each of them and I am facing problems with the outgoing bandwidth from these servers. Actually they are working better with big packets (2-3Gbps) however this is far away from maximum 2x10G possible. With smaller packets the performance drops to about 700Mbps. The CPU usage is no more than 15-20%. Checked the lanes (queues) and it is negociated at PCI-E x8. Tried optimizing the linux kernel, deactivated iptables and checked with the driver from the site and no change.

Tried also installing another card in the Supermicro server and performance is better, so this would mean that the problem is not about the CPU/OS.

I have no idea what can I do more. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: So what are the problems you are having? Are you expecting the NIC to perform faster or something else?

Comment: Yes. 2x10G NIC should perform faster than 700Mbps.

Comment: What is it supposed to perform at?